Java FX in Eclipse
`Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
`

I want to make a JavaFX application using Eclipse, but I have this error.

I will work with CSV files.


I'm guessing this has to do with your [Java] project setup in Eclipse. What Eclipse version are you using? What JDK are you using? Some JDKs include JavaFX and some do not.

Follow the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Related question on using a modular project in Eclipse with Gradle.  I don't personally recommend Gradle, but that is the technology used in the related question, hence my answer there using that technology.  As Basil notes, likely the easiest thing to get started would be a JDK that includes JavaFX and creating a non-modular project (then you don't need to worry about Java modules and external build systems), but as soon as you need to start adding any 3rd party libraries, use a build system (I recommend Maven unless familiar with Gradle).

Just to clarify, could using a jdk with built in jfx help in producing a unit deployable elsewhere?

@g00se if you ask a question for that, you will get an answer.

You need an implementation of JavaFX. (Swing is bundled with all implementations of Java SE, but not JavaFX.)
Nowadays that means obtaining a copy of the OpenJFX libraries produced from the open‑source project co‑led by Gluon and Oracle.
Easiest way to get started is to obtain a JDK that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries. Two vendors provide such an edition of their JDK/JRE products:

Azul Systems
BellSoft

One convenient way to obtain such a JDK is the SDKMAN! tool. Look for “fx” items in the list of available JDKs.
For more info:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/
Search Stack Overflow for many existing Questions and Answers, especially those by jewelsea and James_D, and a few by me.


If downloading the Azul Zulu JDK or the Bellsoft Liberica JDK manually from their websites, make sure to choose the "JDK FX" and "Full JDK" packages, respectively; otherwise, JavaFX won't be included.

Be sure to check the various licensing options of each JDK and verify that they apply to your development and production environments.
